# Difference on iPhone and Android, css

Tags: android, css, iphone, difference

How come my webdesign looks so different on iphone and android. All my elements match up exactly as i want them on android, but wrong on iPhone, even though i'm using Chrome as browser on both? 
I even designed the site from iPhone proportions using google dev tool, and yet it fits android better than iPhone?

http://e-daktik.dk/bonde5a.html

Edit:
*The main problem is that the text wont fit in the boxes. But other things are going wrong aswell, for expample, some of the icons pictures get out of proportion on iPhone. But yeah, i see now that i should never have made the dialogue boxes as pictures, but should have made it as CSS background. That would atleast fix some of the problems.*

ty

```
body {
  background-image: url(http://e-daktik.dk/messengerbaggrund.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.icon {
  animation: shake 0.5s;
animation-iteration-count: 20;
animation-delay: 10s;
}

@keyframes shake {
0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
30% { transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
70% { transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
90% { transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}
}

.npcbox1 {
  position: relative;
}

.npcbox1text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 17%;
  padding-right: 35%;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.pbox {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-delay: 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
0% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
0% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 1;}
}

.fadeIn {
-webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
animation-name: fadeIn;
}

.pboxtext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 43%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.npcbox2 {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-delay: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
0% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
0% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 1;}
}

.fadeIn {
-webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
animation-name: fadeIn;
}

.npcbox2text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 17%;
  padding-right: 35%;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.saybox {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: what are those differences?

Comment: The text in the top box looks misplaced regardless of screen width, although anything less than 858px wide and it spills out. I would not recommend having those dialogue boxes as images. Instead, use CSS backgrounds so they can scale with the text contained within.

Comment: The main problem is that the text wont fit in the boxes. But other things are going wrong aswell, for expample, some of the icons pictures get out of proportion on iPhone. But yeah, i see now that i should never have made the dialogue boxes as pictures, but should have made it as CSS background. That would atleast fix some of the problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it cross platform

```
@keyframes shake {
 0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
 10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
 20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
 30% { transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
 40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
 50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
 60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
 70% { transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
 80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
 90% { transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
 100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes shake {
   0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
 10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
 20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
 30% { transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
 40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
 50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
 60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
 70% { transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
 80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
 90% { transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
 100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes shake {
 0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
 10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
 20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
 30% { transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
 40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
 50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
 60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
 70% { transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
 80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
 90% { transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
 100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes shake {
       0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
 10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
 20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
 30% { transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
 40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
 50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
 60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
 70% { transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
 80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
 90% { transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
 100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}


.icon {
   -webkit-animation: shake 5s 0.5s; /* Safari 4+ */
   -moz-animation:    shake 5s 0.5s; /* Fx 5+ */
   -o-animation:      shake 5s 0.5s; /* Opera 12+ */
   animation:         shake 5s 0.5s; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
```